# Как определить на какие селекторы querySelectorAll тратит много времени?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, профилирование, инструменты-разработчика

Профайлер показывает, что значительное время тратится на выполнение `querySelectorAll`. Как определить, на каких именно селекторах наблюдается потяря производительности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предложу экзотический метод. В JavaScript можно менять объекты "на лету". Причем изменению подвержены не только свойства, но и методы. Можно попытаться реализовать свой маленький профайлер с использованием "monkey-patching" техники:

```
document.querySelectorAll = (function() {
    var orig = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document),
        storage = {};

    var query = function(s) {
        if (!storage[s]) {
            storage[s] = {
                totalTime: 0,
                count: 0
            };
        }

        var start = performance.now(),
            res = orig(s),
            deltaT = performance.now() - start;

        storage[s].totalTime += deltaT;
        storage[s].count++;

        return res;
    };

    query.getResults = function() {
        return storage;
    };

    return query;
})();

// Кусок, работающий с DOM
document.querySelectorAll('.question div div a');

// Получаем информацию о том что и как долго работало
console.dir(document.querySelectorAll.getResults());
```

Comment: Ну во-первых, не `document.querySelectorAll`, а `Element.prototype.querySelectorAll`. Во-вторых, гораздо точнее будет не `Date.now()`, а `performance.now()`. Ну и хотелось бы что-то встроенное в хром, что потом не надо разгребать руками.

Comment: @Qwertiy, с пунктом 2 согласен, подправил ответ. А что касается п.1, то на момент выполнения кода, объект `document` уже существует и изменение `Element.prototype.querySelectorAll` ничего не даст. Как бы то ни было, мой ответ скорее proof-of-concept, именно поэтому я и оговорился, что метод экзотический ;)

Comment: Не важно, существует объект, или нет, изменение метода в прототипе влияет и на уже созданные объекты. А твой вариант неправильный, поскольку я могу вызывать метод на дюбом элементе, а не только на документе, а у тебя только с документом профилироваться будут запросы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, хм.. по поводу обновления прототипа я был не прав, признаю. **Но** `document` не является экземпляром `Element` (`document instanceof Element === false`).

Comment: Хм.. Значит надо менять оба.

Answer (score 0):

При работе с селекторами я бы выделил 2 простых правила:

1. Поиск элементов осуществляется справа-налево. Т.е. в конструкции `.parent div` вначале будут найдены все дивы на странице, а потом уже будут выделены те, что имеют общего родителя с классом `parent`. Что из этого следует? Не стоит подробно расписывать вложенность. Конструкция `.parent a` будет работать быстрее чем `.parent div span a`. Если же всё таки подобная потребность возникает, то лучше перепроектировать этот участок кода. Добавить классов.
2. Псевдо-селекторы работают очень медленно, всякие там `:first-child, :last-child`. Так что стоит избегать поиска по ним.

Comment: Меня интересует именно профилирование. А второй пункт - это вообще неправда.